# Проверка кода Python. Проверка введенных значений. Тестовые данные

Tags: python, математика, данные

Ку

Буду благодарна за пару подсказок

Необходимо было составить программу, производящую некоторые вычисления (их я прописала в комментариях к коду).
Составила:

```
import math
x = int(input('Введите любое число '))
a = int(input('Введите любое число '))
b = int(input('Введите любое число '))
#вычисляем первое выражение (tg(x)+3.73)/4x
y = (math.tan(x)+3.73)/4*x
print('f(x) = ',y)
#вычисляем второе выражение z= (7y+ 3*sin(a)+sqrt(b^2+19))/7y+sqrt(b^2+19)+2
c = 7*y #дополнительная промежуточная переменная 1
d = math.sqrt(math.pow(b,2)+19) #дополнительная промежуточная переменная 2
e = 3*math.sin(a) #дополнительная промежуточная переменная 3
z = (c + e + d) / (c + d + 2)
print('f(y,a,b) = ',z)
```

Также есть несколько требований к программе:

**

> *При вводе данных необходимо выводить на экран поясняющие надписи (что требуется ввести, какие имеются ограничения, например, ввод
> переменной, из которой в дальнейшем придётся извлекать корень,
> необходимо снабдить выводом сообщения  «Введите неотрицательное число:
> »).*

**

Насколько понимаю, мои числа могут быть любыми, в том числе отрицательными или дробными. Поэтому оставляю как есть.

> *В теле программы в виде комментария необходимо привести набор тестовых данных: значения переменных x, a, b и ожидаемые результаты
> расчетов для y и z (в зависимости от вида функций 3-5 тестовых
> наборов, должно быть продемонстрировано, что правильно вычисляется
> значение y и значение z).*

Вот тут мне потребуются пояснения, как это верно прописать и где?

Заранее спасибо :3

Comment: Комментарии игнорируются интерпретатором, их можно разместить где угодно (скорее всего там, где преподаватель обратит на них внимание) в формате, например, `Ввод: <Конкретные значения x, a, b>. Вывод: <правильный ответ>` (ну не знаю, первое, что в голову пришло). Это исключительно требование именно конкретно вашего преподавателя, а не какой-то общепринятый стандарт разработки. В реальной разработке вас попросили бы тесты написать, которые можно было бы запустить и автоматически проверить соответствие программы заявленным требованиям.

Comment: Здесь: ` int(input('Введите любое число '))` вы пишите про любое число, хотя преобразуете к целому. (`.5` - вызовет ошибку).